# Can't create a table because a foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

```
create table hospitals(
    IDhospital int(2),
    name varchar(30),
    site varchar(30),
    foreign key (CODregion)
        references to regions(IDregion)
);
```

MySql says: the column "CODregion" doesn't exist in table

WHY??!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `foreign key` declaration describes a column that has already been declared.  So you want something like this:

```
create table hospitals (
    IDhospital int(2),
    name varchar(30),
    site varchar(30),
    CODregion int,
    foreign key (CODregion) references to regions(IDregion)
);
```

The type of `CODregion` needs to match the type of `IDregion`.  This assumes the type is `int`.

Note:  There really is no value to specifying a formatting length for `int`.  Just use `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Your regions table should look something like this -

```
create table regions (
IDregion int(2), 
name varchar(30),
PRIMARY KEY (IDregion));
```

You have to define IDregion as a primary key.

Now you can run the following query -

```
create table hospitals (
IDhospital int(2), 
name varchar(30), 
site varchar(30), 
CODregion int(2),
foreign key (CODregion) references regions(IDregion));
```

In mysql you have to define the column in the create table syntax before using it as a foreign key constraint.

Hope this helps.